# import * as firebase from 'firebase' no longer working as of Angular 6 update

Tags: angular, firebase, import, angular6

I recently updated my Angular 5 project to Angular 6 and I've been trying to build and deploy all day. My latest problem is one with importing - it was working fine before.

The error now says `cannot find module 'firebase'` in my import.

[image: cannot find module 'firebase']

Comment: is it for sure in your `package.json` as a dependency and did you `npm install` after the update? If so, npm can be weird, as can Intellisense. a good ol' `rm -rf /node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install` may fix it.

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Answer (score 11):

For Angular 6+ import firebase core and services as follows:

```js
/*
* reduce the amount of code that your app uses by 
* only including the features that you need.
*/

// import core firebase client (required)
import firebase from '@firebase/app';

// import Firebase Authentication (optional)
import '@firebase/auth';

// import Firebase Realtime Database (optional)
import '@firebase/database';

// import Cloud Firestore (optional)
import '@firebase/firestore';
```

Se [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) for more information.